# Good reference book for fibre bundles and principal bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I want to read the theory of fibre bundle, vector bundle and principal G bundle. Also about classifying spaces. Can someone suggest me good references for this material.

Comment: Maybe you can check out Dale Husmoller's "Fibre bundles"

Comment: R. Cohen has a good set of notes "The Topology of Fiber Bundles", which are free online if you google for them.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to have a look at :

- Topology of Fiber bundles by Steenrod
- Topology and groupoids by Ronald Brown ( this text is also free for download in pdf format if you google search)
- Foundations of Differential Geometry by Nomizu and Kobayashi ( not a very good text to learn from but it is considered the encyclopedia of differential geometry).
- A User's Guide to Algebraic Topology by Dodson.